# Cocos2d-x Javascript Bindings supported platforms?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I've asked this question on the Cocos2d-x forums and haven't gotten a reply. Sadly that seems par for the course for those forums :/

My question is, are the docs that state the JavaScript bindings for cocos2d-x are only supported Windows, iPhone, and Android correct? I would love to be able to target iOS, Android, Windows, Mac, and Linux all with the same code base. I'm also extremely fluent in JavaScript and would much prefer to use that if possible. I know I could use cocos2d-html5 but I would rather go native.

Any answers for this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to support that many platforms with native technology and javascript your best option is actually to use Unity (Unityscript equals Javascript).

Comment: Unity is slight overkill for a 2D game. I've been down that road. Also, it's pretty cost prohibitive if you need/want the Pro version.

Comment: ok but if you want native then last time i checked cocos2d-x can't do mac. And with non-native cocos2d-html5 I don't know how well that runs on mobile, at least inside a uiwebview js is limited to 10 mb.

Comment: I've actually been reading up again on Unity (been a while since I've last used it). Seeing as it's free, it's tempting. However, I'm not too sure how well the community takes to those splash screens that get forced on you if you don't upgrade to Pro. $4,500 for all Pro versions is rather steep for an indie. I'm also not too sure which features I would be requiring (if any) out of Pro for my new game.